# How to generate 'DDL' of table in which the 'TABLE_COLLATION' is not 'latin1_swedish_ci' but 'utf8_general_ci'

Tags: mysql, database, spring, character-encoding

I am a newbie!
I had modified `default-character-set=utf8` and `character-set-server=utf8` in the file named `my.ini`.
But the generated table has `TABLE_COLLATION=latin1_swedish_ci`

[image: my table info]

[image: my docs]

Note:the table generated by JPA hibernate-implements:
[image]

Comment: Yeah,the charset of DDL is latin1 not utf8,why?

Comment: Next time please post code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not specified charset/collation in CREATE TABLE statement, then new table will be created with database charset/collation.

So, for existed database with latin1 charset you should do something like this -

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  column1 VARCHAR(20),
  column2 VARCHAR(20)
)
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

---

```
-- show current database name
SELECT DATABASE();

-- show CREATE DATABASE statement with charset\collation for DB
SHOW CREATE DATABASE <database name>;
```

Comment: But the default setting had been modified into `utf8` not `latin1`.

Comment: Check the DATABASE where you are trying to create new table. I have added some notices in my answer.

Comment: oh,sorry,it's ok now! I delete the old database and create a new one,then it works!Thank you so much.